# Error when looping to produce subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, dataframe, subplot

I have a question about an error I receive when looping to plot multiple subplots from a data frame.

My data frame has many columns, of which I loop over to have a subplot of each column.

This is my **code**

```
 def plot(df):
    channels=[]
    for i in df:
        channels.append(i)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(channels), sharex=True, figsize=(50,100))

    plot=0    
    for j in df: 

        ax[plot].plot(df["%s" % j])
        ax[plot].set_xlabel('%s' % j)
        plot=plot+1

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

I get the plot produced fine, but also an empty frame and the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\AClayton\WinPython-64bit-2.7.5.3\python-2.7.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 538, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:/Users/AClayton/Desktop/Data/TS.py", line 67, in <module>
    plot(all_data)
  File "C:/Users/AClayton/Desktop/Data/TS.py", line 49, in plot
    ax[plot].plot(reader["%s" % j])
TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object does not support indexing
```

I can't see where this error comes from if the first plot is produced fine, or why the second figure is produced?

Thanks for any insight

Answer (score 65, accepted):

If you plot multiple subplots, the `plt.subplots()` returns the axes in an array, that array allows indexing like you do with `ax[plot]`. When only 1 subplot is created, by default it returns the axes itself, not the axes within an array.

So your error occurs when `len(channels)` equals 1. You can suppress this behavior by setting `squeeze=False` in the `.subplots()` command. This forces it to always return a 'Rows x Cols' sized array with the axes, even if its a single one.

So:

```
 def plot(df):
    channels=[]
    for i in df:
        channels.append(i)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(len(channels),1, sharex=True, figsize=(50,100), squeeze=False)

    plot=0    
    for j in df: 

        ax[plot,0].plot(df["%s" % j])
        ax[plot,0].set_xlabel('%s' % j)
        plot=plot+1

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

By adding the `squeeze` keyword you always get a 2D array in return, so the indexing for a subplot changes to `ax[plot,0]`. I have also specifically added the amount of columns (1 in this case).